# Error while using npm i -g @angular/cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

New to Angular 4 and trying to configure the Angular 4 with VS-2017 for an POC. Trying to install @angular/cli in my pc but getting below error

> Error Message: 12109 error code EINTEGRITY 12110 error
>   sha512-dRHYcs9LvG9cHgdPzjiI+/eS7e1xRhULrcyOx04RZQsszNJXU2SL9CyG60yLnge282Qq5nwTv+ieK2fH+WPZmA==
>   integrity checksum failed when using sha512: wanted
>   sha512-dRHYcs9LvG9cHgdPzjiI+/eS7e1xRhULrcyOx04RZQsszNJXU2SL9CyG60yLnge282Qq5nwTv+ieK2fH+WPZmA==
>   but got
>   sha512-EEtomIMpNtMIU69zpKhGDta5eeOBCkFDtFmL+DocaMyoMaO2RRn+Nr/Wu+gFhPOGpgMuAcb3C2asNYy5uJIT7Q==.
>   (18725 bytes) 12111 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Versions

Output from: `ng --version`.
'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Output from: `node --version` 
v8.4.0

and `npm --version`:
5.5.1
Operating System: Windows 10

Repro steps

Step 1: Executed 'npm i -g @angular/cli'
Observed behavior

Comment: You need to run the command prompt as an administrator

Comment: This has been tried but still same error

Answer (score 0):

After multiple restart of system and connecting to personal network issue got resolved.